# Inheriting one GWT module having entry point class in another GWT module having its own entry point class

Tags: gwt

Can we inherit GWT module having entry point class into another GWT module having its own entry point class.

What I did is just inherited one module in another module, but it loads both the modules any suggestion how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,We can inherit one GWT Module into another,even though both have `EntryPoint Classes`.

As of now  you might specify like below :

```
<inherits name="package.EntryPointClass2" />
```

Yes,that exactly invoke the `onModuleLoad` of `EntryPointClass2` for sure.But you may not need that functionality.

In order to use the both modules together you can follow @David's [Solution](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/tips-on-organizing-gwt-modules/) of  organizing GWT modules.

[And it seems the “right” answer is “it depends”.](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/02/22/structuring-gwt-modules-for-large-applications/)